# ASP VB Upload Files, Don't use original file name! Use a URL Scheme to name uploaded files.

Tags: file-upload, asp-classic, vbscript

Good Day Everyone!

I am working on a ASP VB Script that I found online for free. It works great on my web server but the solution will only use the original filename to save to the web server's directories.

I am looking for a ASP File Uploader Solution to where I can pass a URL:

http://globalbanke.com/uploadFiles.asp?CustomName=Red

Then the uploader page opens and the user can load the file and then the file is saved on the server as "Red"

My Web Page Hosted:

#

```
<%@ Language=VBScript %>
<% 
option explicit 
Response.Expires = -1
Server.ScriptTimeout = 600
' All communication must be in UTF-8, including the response back from the request
Session.CodePage  = 65001
%>

<!-- #include file="freeaspupload.asp" -->
<%


  ' ****************************************************
  ' Change the value of the variable below to the pathname
  ' of a directory with write permissions, for example "C:\Inetpub\wwwroot"
  ' ****************************************************

  Dim uploadsDirVar
  uploadsDirVar = "c:\inetpub\wwwroot\Test" 


  ' Note: this file uploadTester.asp is just an example to demonstrate
  ' the capabilities of the freeASPUpload.asp class. There are no plans
  ' to add any new features to uploadTester.asp itself. Feel free to add
  ' your own code. If you are building a content management system, you
  ' may also want to consider this script: http://www.webfilebrowser.com/

function OutputForm()
%>
    <form name="frmSend" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" accept-charset="utf-8" action="uploadTester.asp" onSubmit="return onSubmitForm();">
    <B>File names:</B><br>
    File 1: <input type="file" name="attach1" id="photo_input" data-sigil="photo-input"><br>
    <br> 
    <input type="text" id="data" name="enter_a_number"><br>
    <input style="margin-top:4" type=submit value="Upload">
    </form>
<%
end function

function TestEnvironment()
    Dim fso, fileName, testFile, streamTest
    TestEnvironment = ""
    Set fso = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    if not fso.FolderExists(uploadsDirVar) then
        TestEnvironment = "<B>Folder " & uploadsDirVar & " does not exist.</B><br>The value of your uploadsDirVar is incorrect. Open uploadTester.asp in an editor and change the value of uploadsDirVar to the pathname of a directory with write permissions."
        exit function
    end if
    fileName = uploadsDirVar & "\test.txt"
    on error resume next
    Set testFile = fso.CreateTextFile(fileName, true)
    If Err.Number<>0 then
        TestEnvironment = "<B>Folder " & uploadsDirVar & " does not have write permissions.</B><br>The value of your uploadsDirVar is incorrect. Open uploadTester.asp in an editor and change the value of uploadsDirVar to the pathname of a directory with write permissions."
        exit function
    end if
    Err.Clear
    testFile.Close
    fso.DeleteFile(fileName)
    If Err.Number<>0 then
        TestEnvironment = "<B>Folder " & uploadsDirVar & " does not have delete permissions</B>, although it does have write permissions.<br>Change the permissions for IUSR_<I>computername</I> on this folder."
        exit function
    end if
    Err.Clear
    Set streamTest = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    If Err.Number<>0 then
        TestEnvironment = "<B>The ADODB object <I>Stream</I> is not available in your server.</B><br>Check the Requirements page for information about upgrading your ADODB libraries."
        exit function
    end if
    Set streamTest = Nothing
end function

function SaveFiles
    Dim Upload, fileName, fileSize, ks, i, fileKey

    Set Upload = New FreeASPUpload
    Upload.Save(uploadsDirVar)

    ' If something fails inside the script, but the exception is handled
    If Err.Number<>0 then Exit function

    SaveFiles = ""
    fileName = "real"
    ks = Upload.UploadedFiles.keys
    if (UBound(ks) <> -1) then
        SaveFiles = "<B>Files uploaded:</B> "
        for each fileKey in Upload.UploadedFiles.keys
            SaveFiles = SaveFiles & Upload.UploadedFiles(fileKey).FileName & " (" & Upload.UploadedFiles(fileKey).Length & "B) "
        next
    else
        SaveFiles = "No file selected for upload or the file name specified in the upload form does not correspond to a valid file in the system."
    end if
end function
%>


<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Test Free ASP Upload 2.0</TITLE>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<style>
BODY {background-color: white;font-family:arial; font-size:12}
</style>
<script>
function onSubmitForm() {
    var formDOMObj = document.frmSend;
    if (formDOMObj.attach1.value == "" && formDOMObj.attach2.value == "" && formDOMObj.attach3.value == "" && formDOMObj.attach4.value == "" )
        alert("Please press the Browse button and pick a file.")
    else
        return true;
    return false;
}
</script>

</HEAD>

<BODY>

<br><br>
<div style="border-bottom: #A91905 2px solid;font-size:16">Upload files to your server</div>
<%
Dim diagnostics
if Request.ServerVariables("REQUEST_METHOD") <> "POST" then
    diagnostics = TestEnvironment()
    if diagnostics<>"" then
        response.write "<div style=""margin-left:20; margin-top:30; margin-right:30; margin-bottom:30;"">"
        response.write diagnostics
        response.write "<p>After you correct this problem, reload the page."
        response.write "</div>"
    else
        response.write "<div style=""margin-left:150"">"
        OutputForm()
        response.write "</div>"
    end if
else
    response.write "<div style=""margin-left:150"">"
    OutputForm()
    response.write SaveFiles()
    response.write "<br><br></div>"
end if

%>


</BODY>
</HTML>
```

#

I am using the upload.save() method.
This line here:

filePath = path & request.querystring("CustomName")

This gives me a server error, but if I change it to "test.txt" it saves it as such.

So my question is, How do I use the URL Query as filename for the server?

Here is the ASP Class Methods

```
<%
'  For examples, documentation, and your own free copy, go to:
'  http://www.freeaspupload.net
'  Note: You can copy and use this script for free and you can make changes
'  to the code, but you cannot remove the above comment.

'Changes:
'Aug 2, 2005: Add support for checkboxes and other input elements with multiple values
'Jan 6, 2009: Lars added ASP_CHUNK_SIZE
'Sep 3, 2010: Enforce UTF-8 everywhere; new function to convert byte array to unicode string

const DEFAULT_ASP_CHUNK_SIZE = 200000

const adModeReadWrite = 3
const adTypeBinary = 1
const adTypeText = 2
const adSaveCreateOverWrite = 2

Class FreeASPUpload
    Public UploadedFiles
    Public FormElements

    Private VarArrayBinRequest
    Private StreamRequest
    Private uploadedYet
    Private internalChunkSize

    Private Sub Class_Initialize()
        Set UploadedFiles = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        Set FormElements = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        Set StreamRequest = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
        StreamRequest.Type = adTypeText
        StreamRequest.Open
        uploadedYet = false
        internalChunkSize = DEFAULT_ASP_CHUNK_SIZE
    End Sub

    Private Sub Class_Terminate()
        If IsObject(UploadedFiles) Then
            UploadedFiles.RemoveAll()
            Set UploadedFiles = Nothing
        End If
        If IsObject(FormElements) Then
            FormElements.RemoveAll()
            Set FormElements = Nothing
        End If
        StreamRequest.Close
        Set StreamRequest = Nothing
    End Sub

    Public Property Get Form(sIndex)
        Form = ""
        If FormElements.Exists(LCase(sIndex)) Then Form = FormElements.Item(LCase(sIndex))
    End Property

    Public Property Get Files()
        Files = UploadedFiles.Items
    End Property

    Public Property Get Exists(sIndex)
            Exists = false
            If FormElements.Exists(LCase(sIndex)) Then Exists = true
    End Property

    Public Property Get FileExists(sIndex)
        FileExists = false
            if UploadedFiles.Exists(LCase(sIndex)) then FileExists = true
    End Property

    Public Property Get chunkSize()
        chunkSize = internalChunkSize
    End Property

    Public Property Let chunkSize(sz)
        internalChunkSize = sz
    End Property

    'Calls Upload to extract the data from the binary request and then saves the uploaded files
    Public Sub Save(path)
        Dim streamFile, fileItem, filePath

        if Right(path, 1) <> "\" then path = path & "\"

        if not uploadedYet then Upload

        For Each fileItem In UploadedFiles.Items
            filePath = path & request.querystring("CustomName")
            Set streamFile = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
            streamFile.Type = adTypeBinary
            streamFile.Open
            StreamRequest.Position=fileItem.Start
            StreamRequest.CopyTo streamFile, fileItem.Length
            streamFile.SaveToFile filePath, adSaveCreateOverWrite
            streamFile.close
            Set streamFile = Nothing
            fileItem.Path = filePath
         Next
    End Sub

    public sub SaveOne(path, num, byref outFileName, byref outLocalFileName)
        Dim streamFile, fileItems, fileItem, fs

        set fs = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        if Right(path, 1) <> "\" then path = path & "\"

        if not uploadedYet then Upload
        if UploadedFiles.Count > 0 then
            fileItems = UploadedFiles.Items
            set fileItem = fileItems(num)

            outFileName = fileItem.FileName
            outLocalFileName = GetFileName(path, outFileName)

            Set streamFile = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
            streamFile.Type = adTypeBinary
            streamFile.Open
            StreamRequest.Position = fileItem.Start
            StreamRequest.CopyTo streamFile, fileItem.Length
            streamFile.SaveToFile path & outLocalFileName, adSaveCreateOverWrite
            streamFile.close
            Set streamFile = Nothing
            fileItem.Path = path & filename
        end if
    end sub

    Public Function SaveBinRequest(path) ' For debugging purposes
        StreamRequest.SaveToFile path & "\debugStream.bin", 2
    End Function

    Public Sub DumpData() 'only works if files are plain text
        Dim i, aKeys, f
        response.write "Form Items:<br>"
        aKeys = FormElements.Keys
        For i = 0 To FormElements.Count -1 ' Iterate the array
            response.write aKeys(i) & " = " & FormElements.Item(aKeys(i)) & "<BR>"
        Next
        response.write "Uploaded Files:<br>"
        For Each f In UploadedFiles.Items
            response.write "Name: " & f.FileName & "<br>"
            response.write "Type: " & f.ContentType & "<br>"
            response.write "Start: " & f.Start & "<br>"
            response.write "Size: " & f.Length & "<br>"
         Next
    End Sub

    Public Sub Upload()
        Dim nCurPos, nDataBoundPos, nLastSepPos
        Dim nPosFile, nPosBound
        Dim sFieldName, osPathSep, auxStr
        Dim readBytes, readLoop, tmpBinRequest

        'RFC1867 Tokens
        Dim vDataSep
        Dim tNewLine, tDoubleQuotes, tTerm, tFilename, tName, tContentDisp, tContentType
        tNewLine = String2Byte(Chr(13))
        tDoubleQuotes = String2Byte(Chr(34))
        tTerm = String2Byte("--")
        tFilename = String2Byte("filename=""")
        tName = String2Byte("name=""")
        tContentDisp = String2Byte("Content-Disposition")
        tContentType = String2Byte("Content-Type:")

        uploadedYet = true

        on error resume next
            ' Copy binary request to a byte array, on which functions like InstrB and others can be used to search for separation tokens
            readBytes = internalChunkSize
            VarArrayBinRequest = Request.BinaryRead(readBytes)
            VarArrayBinRequest = midb(VarArrayBinRequest, 1, lenb(VarArrayBinRequest))
            Do Until readBytes < 1
                tmpBinRequest = Request.BinaryRead(readBytes)
                if readBytes > 0 then
                    VarArrayBinRequest = VarArrayBinRequest & midb(tmpBinRequest, 1, lenb(tmpBinRequest))
                end if
            Loop
            StreamRequest.WriteText(VarArrayBinRequest)
            StreamRequest.Flush()
            if Err.Number <> 0 then 
                response.write "<br><br><B>System reported this error:</B><p>"
                response.write Err.Description & "<p>"
                response.write "The most likely cause for this error is the incorrect setup of AspMaxRequestEntityAllowed in IIS MetaBase. Please see instructions in the <A HREF='http://www.freeaspupload.net/freeaspupload/requirements.asp'>requirements page of freeaspupload.net</A>.<p>"
                Exit Sub
            end if
        on error goto 0 'reset error handling

        nCurPos = FindToken(tNewLine,1) 'Note: nCurPos is 1-based (and so is InstrB, MidB, etc)

        If nCurPos <= 1  Then Exit Sub

        'vDataSep is a separator like -----------------------------21763138716045
        vDataSep = MidB(VarArrayBinRequest, 1, nCurPos-1)

        'Start of current separator
        nDataBoundPos = 1

        'Beginning of last line
        nLastSepPos = FindToken(vDataSep & tTerm, 1)

        Do Until nDataBoundPos = nLastSepPos

            nCurPos = SkipToken(tContentDisp, nDataBoundPos)
            nCurPos = SkipToken(tName, nCurPos)
            sFieldName = ExtractField(tDoubleQuotes, nCurPos)

            nPosFile = FindToken(tFilename, nCurPos)
            nPosBound = FindToken(vDataSep, nCurPos)

            If nPosFile <> 0 And  nPosFile < nPosBound Then
                Dim oUploadFile
                Set oUploadFile = New UploadedFile

                nCurPos = SkipToken(tFilename, nCurPos)
                auxStr = ExtractField(tDoubleQuotes, nCurPos)
                ' We are interested only in the name of the file, not the whole path
                ' Path separator is \ in windows, / in UNIX
                ' While IE seems to put the whole pathname in the stream, Mozilla seem to 
                ' only put the actual file name, so UNIX paths may be rare. But not impossible.
                osPathSep = "\"
                if InStr(auxStr, osPathSep) = 0 then osPathSep = "/"
                oUploadFile.FileName = Right(auxStr, Len(auxStr)-InStrRev(auxStr, osPathSep))

                if (Len(oUploadFile.FileName) > 0) then 'File field not left empty
                    nCurPos = SkipToken(tContentType, nCurPos)

                    auxStr = ExtractField(tNewLine, nCurPos)
                    ' NN on UNIX puts things like this in the stream:
                    '    ?? python py type=?? python application/x-python
                    oUploadFile.ContentType = Right(auxStr, Len(auxStr)-InStrRev(auxStr, " "))
                    nCurPos = FindToken(tNewLine, nCurPos) + 4 'skip empty line

                    oUploadFile.Start = nCurPos+1
                    oUploadFile.Length = FindToken(vDataSep, nCurPos) - 2 - nCurPos

                    If oUploadFile.Length > 0 Then UploadedFiles.Add LCase(sFieldName), oUploadFile
                End If
            Else
                Dim nEndOfData, fieldValueUniStr
                nCurPos = FindToken(tNewLine, nCurPos) + 4 'skip empty line
                nEndOfData = FindToken(vDataSep, nCurPos) - 2
                fieldValueuniStr = ConvertUtf8BytesToString(nCurPos, nEndOfData-nCurPos)
                If Not FormElements.Exists(LCase(sFieldName)) Then 
                    FormElements.Add LCase(sFieldName), fieldValueuniStr
                else
                    FormElements.Item(LCase(sFieldName))= FormElements.Item(LCase(sFieldName)) & ", " & fieldValueuniStr
                end if 

            End If

            'Advance to next separator
            nDataBoundPos = FindToken(vDataSep, nCurPos)
        Loop
    End Sub

    Private Function SkipToken(sToken, nStart)
        SkipToken = InstrB(nStart, VarArrayBinRequest, sToken)
        If SkipToken = 0 then
            Response.write "Error in parsing uploaded binary request. The most likely cause for this error is the incorrect setup of AspMaxRequestEntityAllowed in IIS MetaBase. Please see instructions in the <A HREF='http://www.freeaspupload.net/freeaspupload/requirements.asp'>requirements page of freeaspupload.net</A>.<p>"
            Response.End
        end if
        SkipToken = SkipToken + LenB(sToken)
    End Function

    Private Function FindToken(sToken, nStart)
        FindToken = InstrB(nStart, VarArrayBinRequest, sToken)
    End Function

    Private Function ExtractField(sToken, nStart)
        Dim nEnd
        nEnd = InstrB(nStart, VarArrayBinRequest, sToken)
        If nEnd = 0 then
            Response.write "Error in parsing uploaded binary request."
            Response.End
        end if
        ExtractField = ConvertUtf8BytesToString(nStart, nEnd-nStart)
    End Function

    'String to byte string conversion
    Private Function String2Byte(sString)
        Dim i
        For i = 1 to Len(sString)
           String2Byte = String2Byte & ChrB(AscB(Mid(sString,i,1)))
        Next
    End Function

    Private Function ConvertUtf8BytesToString(start, length)    
        StreamRequest.Position = 0

        Dim objStream
        Dim strTmp

        ' init stream
        Set objStream = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
        objStream.Charset = "utf-8"
        objStream.Mode = adModeReadWrite
        objStream.Type = adTypeBinary
        objStream.Open

        ' write bytes into stream
        StreamRequest.Position = start+1
        StreamRequest.CopyTo objStream, length
        objStream.Flush

        ' rewind stream and read text
        objStream.Position = 0
        objStream.Type = adTypeText
        strTmp = objStream.ReadText

        ' close up and return
        objStream.Close
        Set objStream = Nothing
        ConvertUtf8BytesToString = strTmp   
    End Function
End Class

Class UploadedFile
    Public ContentType
    Public Start
    Public Length
    Public Path
    Private nameOfFile

    ' Need to remove characters that are valid in UNIX, but not in Windows
    Public Property Let FileName(fN)
        nameOfFile = fN
        nameOfFile = SubstNoReg(nameOfFile, "\", "_")
        nameOfFile = SubstNoReg(nameOfFile, "/", "_")
        nameOfFile = SubstNoReg(nameOfFile, ":", "_")
        nameOfFile = SubstNoReg(nameOfFile, "*", "_")
        nameOfFile = SubstNoReg(nameOfFile, "?", "_")
        nameOfFile = SubstNoReg(nameOfFile, """", "_")
        nameOfFile = SubstNoReg(nameOfFile, "<", "_")
        nameOfFile = SubstNoReg(nameOfFile, ">", "_")
        nameOfFile = SubstNoReg(nameOfFile, "|", "_")
    End Property

    Public Property Get FileName()
        FileName = nameOfFile
    End Property

    'Public Property Get FileN()ame
End Class


' Does not depend on RegEx, which is not available on older VBScript
' Is not recursive, which means it will not run out of stack space
Function SubstNoReg(initialStr, oldStr, newStr)
    Dim currentPos, oldStrPos, skip
    If IsNull(initialStr) Or Len(initialStr) = 0 Then
        SubstNoReg = ""
    ElseIf IsNull(oldStr) Or Len(oldStr) = 0 Then
        SubstNoReg = initialStr
    Else
        If IsNull(newStr) Then newStr = ""
        currentPos = 1
        oldStrPos = 0
        SubstNoReg = ""
        skip = Len(oldStr)
        Do While currentPos <= Len(initialStr)
            oldStrPos = InStr(currentPos, initialStr, oldStr)
            If oldStrPos = 0 Then
                SubstNoReg = SubstNoReg & Mid(initialStr, currentPos, Len(initialStr) - currentPos + 1)
                currentPos = Len(initialStr) + 1
            Else
                SubstNoReg = SubstNoReg & Mid(initialStr, currentPos, oldStrPos - currentPos) & newStr
                currentPos = oldStrPos + skip
            End If
        Loop
    End If
End Function

Function GetFileName(strSaveToPath, FileName)
'This function is used when saving a file to check there is not already a file with the same name so that you don't overwrite it.
'It adds numbers to the filename e.g. file.gif becomes file1.gif becomes file2.gif and so on.
'It keeps going until it returns a filename that does not exist.
'You could just create a filename from the ID field but that means writing the record - and it still might exist!
'N.B. Requires strSaveToPath variable to be available - and containing the path to save to
    Dim Counter
    Dim Flag
    Dim strTempFileName
    Dim FileExt
    Dim NewFullPath
    dim objFSO, p
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Counter = 0
    p = instrrev(FileName, ".")
    FileExt = mid(FileName, p+1)
    strTempFileName = left(FileName, p-1)
    NewFullPath = strSaveToPath & "\" & FileName
    Flag = False

    Do Until Flag = True
        If objFSO.FileExists(NewFullPath) = False Then
            Flag = True
            GetFileName = Mid(NewFullPath, InstrRev(NewFullPath, "\") + 1)
        Else
            Counter = Counter + 1
            NewFullPath = strSaveToPath & "\" & strTempFileName & Counter & "." & FileExt
        End If
    Loop
End Function 

%>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Glad your problem was resolved, please mark the answer that helped you as the correct answer by ticking the empty V icon to the left of that answer.

Answer (score 2):

In the "uploadTester.asp", add a querystring to the action part:

```
action="uploadTester.asp?customname=<%=Request.Querystring("customname")%>"
```

and in the "save" sub in the class file, make the changes as:

```
'Calls Upload to extract the data from the binary request and then saves the uploaded files
Public Sub Save(path)
    Dim streamFile, fileItem, filePath
    Dim sFileName
    if Right(path, 1) <> "\" then path = path & "\"

    if not uploadedYet then Upload

    For Each fileItem In UploadedFiles.Items
        sFileName = request.QueryString("customname")
        if(trim(sFileName)="") then
            sFileName=fileItem.FileName
        end if
        filePath = path & sFileName
        'Response.Write filePath
        'Response.end
        Set streamFile = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
        streamFile.Type = adTypeBinary
        streamFile.Open
        StreamRequest.Position=fileItem.Start
        StreamRequest.CopyTo streamFile, fileItem.Length
        streamFile.SaveToFile filePath, adSaveCreateOverWrite
        streamFile.close
        Set streamFile = Nothing
        fileItem.Path = filePath
     Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Works Perfectly. This will work perfectly in my FileMaker Pro Web Publishing Solution.

Comment: The Code Works as intended with the original post. But I have ran into another issue. iPhone 5 with iOS6 now has the ability to have a <input type="file"> this prompts your iphone to take a new photo or select on from the photo library. But for some reason when I use the FREEASPUPLOADER with "Take a new photo" on the iphone it rotates the picture 90Degrees. Also know that choose from library function does not rotate the picture.

Comment: I have another question. How can I resize the photos on or after the asp upload to have a max size of 640px by whatever?